# Policy not imported using terraform import

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created a role manually using aws console called demo_role. I attached a policy to this role.
I ran

```
terraform import aws_iam_role.demo_role demo_role
```

and it successfully imported it in the state file. However, terraform show doesn't display the policy I attached to it. What did I miss?

output of terraform show

```
aws_iam_role.demo_role:
id = demo_role
arn = arn:aws:iam::***********:role/demo_role
assume_role_policy = {"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service":"lambda.amazonaws.com"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole"}]}
create_date = 2020-01-08T20:39:26Z
description = Allows Lambda functions to call AWS services on your behalf.
force_detach_policies = false
max_session_duration = 3600
name = demo_role
path = /
tags.% = 0
unique_id = *******************
```

Answer (score 1):

Terraform won't import the attached policy automatically due to the fact that it's a separate resource. You need to also import the policy to an  [`aws_iam_role_policy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html) resource. The assume role policy is defined directly on the role itself, which is why it is included.